# Please how can I concatenate two helper methods in another method on the same line?

Tags: java

I am to call two helper methods in a single method to print a white space and an asterix on the same line in a right angle format:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

i need help on how to call the two methods or concatenate the two methods on a single line so as to display the white space and the asterix on the same line?

i have tried using "+" as its used in concatenating variables to a strings but it didn't work in adding two methods on a line.

```
public class PrintingLikeBoss {
    // copy or rewrite the method of Assignment 39.1 here
    public static void printStars(int amount) {
         int i = 0;
        while(amount > i){
            System.out.print("*");
            i++;
            if(i == amount){
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        } 
    }

    public static void printWhitespaces(int amount) {
        // 40.1
        int i = 0;
        while( amount > i){
            System.out.print(" ");
            i++;
            if(i == amount){
                System.out.print("\n");
            }
        }
    }

    public static void printTriangle(int size) {
        // 40.2
        int amount =1;
        while(size > amount){
           printWhitespaces(size);printStars(amount);
            size--;
            amount++;
            if(size == 0){
                printStars(amount);
            }

        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests do not use main, yo can write code here freely!

        printTriangle(5);
   }
}
```

Comment: `if(i == amount){ System.out.print("\n"); }` Just remove this in one function.

Comment: I appreciate this is likely a learning exercise, but this isn't really an appropriate use of (multiple) methods: they simply make it more complicated.